How to create stored procedure in remote server using linked server
I tried to create an stored procedure in a remote server using this way
EXECUTE (N'USE [master]; EXEC sp_executesql N'+ @sqlCommand) AT [LinkedServer]

However I received this error

Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure StoredProcedure, Line 5 [Batch
Start Line 0] 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in
a query batch.

in the sqlCommand has the query similar this
SET @sqlCommand = '
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedName]
    @nameDB varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQLProcessesRep varchar(max);

    --Actions in Stored
END'


You can call sp_executesql directly in the context of the linked server's master database, using four-part naming.
EXEC LinkedServer.master.sys.sp_executesql @sqlCommand;

If the linked server name is in a variable you can even do this dynamically
DECLARE @proc nvarchar(1000) = @dbname + N'.master.sys.sp_executesql';
EXEC @proc @sqlCommand;


Thanks a lot this option EXEC LinkedServer.master.sys.sp_executesql @sqlCommand; works.

well yeah
You have two options:

Remove the USE [master]; before the EXEC, and rely on the user's default database being master
Execute sys.sp_executesql in the context of the master database

Your second option would look like this:
EXECUTE (N'EXEC master.sys.sp_executesql N'+ @sqlCommand) AT [LinkedServer];

If you hit any additional issues, please ask a new question.

Thanks a lot,  is a great solution, regards.
